# Does the temporary B() have its lifetime extended by the initialization of the reference int& ri below?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

This example was taken from §8.5.3/5 (first bullet point) in the C++11 Standard:

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { operator int&(); } b;
int& ri = B();
```

If it does, is there any way to access the temporary `B()`, in the code below?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { };
struct B : A { int i; B(): i(10) {} operator int&() { return i; } } b;

int main()
{
    int& ri = B();
    std::cout << ri << '\n';
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't; I don't know if the standard specifies anything, though.

Comment: it's not extended. (How should the compiler know, in the general case anyway, that `operator int&` returns part of its object instead of something unrelated?

Comment: @chris The Standard says this is valid: `int& ri = B();` and it seems to me the object B() is kept on the stack, as `ri` is a reference to its member `i`.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil, Shoot, I missed the `operator int &`, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the destructor for the temporary B object runs at the end of the full expression, as usual. It is not bound to any reference.

In your second example, `ri` is a reference to an `int` object whose lifetime has ended.

Comment: "ri is a reference to an int object whose lifetime has ended". How come I can print `ri` in the code. `ri` definitly is not a dangling reference.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil, Printing a dangling reference is undefined behaviour. It can "work" or do anything else. But it can't work.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil You can print `ri` because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/273767

Comment: @chris But the example in the Standard doesn't say anything about a dangling reference or UB in this case.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil, It doesn't need to in order for either to be true. The standard's example doesn't have any UB. The reference isn't being used, and even if it was, the implementation of `operator int &` could return a reference to a global variable or something.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0be904a9bb6affd8) should make it clear your example has UB. The example in the standard is meant to illustrate how an `int&` can be bound to a seemingly unrelated instance of type `B` because of the existence of the conversion operator. The example by itself is fine.